# Multiple (extra) accessory checkmarks in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView which has multiple accessory checkmark implemented into it. My problem is, when I click some cells in the tableview it gets checked but there will be some other cell also checked below. I can view it when I scroll down the tableview. I would only want the cell to be checked whichever the user is clicking and not the extra cells. Please let me know how can I do it. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [someData count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.someData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:11];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
        return cell;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];    
            NSArray *arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne count]; i++) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPathImInterestedIn = [arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne objectAtIndex:i];
                UITableViewCell *currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathImInterestedIn];
                [saveData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentCell.textLabel.text]];
            }
         } else {
                [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                NSArray *arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

                for(int i = 0; i < [arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne count]; i++) {
                    NSIndexPath *indexPathImInterestedIn = [arrayOfIndexPathsTableOne objectAtIndex:i];
                    UITableViewCell *currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathImInterestedIn];
                    [saveData removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentCell.textLabel.text]]; 
                }
         }
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a cell reuse problem.

To fix, ensure that each time you return a cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you always set the selection (checkmark) status. That means explicitly setting it true and false as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 things you need:

1. Disable multiple selection on your `UITableView`.
2. Implement `setSelected:(BOOL)selected` in your `UITableViewCell`s and make it select/deselect the cell's sub-views (your checkmarks) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you select table you show check box on it but when you scroll and the cell desapeare and it goes to reusable pool after you scroll back the cell is taken from this pool and it doesn't remember the 'state'.

The solution is create NSMutableArray and in didSelectCellAtIndexPath: method add or remove the indexPath for that cell to the array and in  cellForRowAtIndexPath: check this array and show/hide checkmark base on that table.

Answer (score 0):

dont write this line in cell for row at index path

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

it must be in loadview or viewdidload

Comment: i have tested your code , i found the problem is with UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];   because you are dequeue reusable cell thats why its creating again. you need static cell . one cell object for each row. like this one:- UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];